# Why code isn't evaluate an expression, it output only last digit of expression?

Tags: c, symbols

I need write a code, which  according to the string representing an arithmetic expression, output the value of the expression. Code is working correctly, but it don't evaluate an expression. Maybe part with stacks in wrong?

It output only last digit of expression, but not result:
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Stack {
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int *array;
} Stack;

Stack *createStack(unsigned capacity) {
    Stack *stack = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = (int *)malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return stack;
}

int isEmpty(Stack *stack) {
    return stack->top == -1;
}

int peek(Stack *stack) {
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}

int pop(Stack *stack) {
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return stack->array[stack->top--];
    return -1;
}

void push(Stack *stack, int op) {
    stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
}

int evaluate(char *expression) {
    Stack *stack = createStack(strlen(expression));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(expression); ++i) {
        if (isdigit(expression[i])) {
            int operand = 0;
            while (i < strlen(expression) && isdigit(expression[i]))
                operand = operand * 10 + expression[i++] - '0';
            --i;
            push(stack, operand);
        } else {
            int operand1 = pop(stack);
            int operand2 = pop(stack);
            switch (expression[i]) {
                case '+':
                    push(stack, operand2 + operand1);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    push(stack, operand2 - operand1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(stack);
}

int main() {
    char expression[100];
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1. Evaluate an arithmetic expression\n");
        printf("2. Quit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter an arithmetic expression: ");
                scanf("%s", expression);
                int result = evaluate(expression);
                printf("Result: %d\n", result);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice. Try again.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Code is working correctly, but it don't evaluate an expression.* - this is self-contradictory sentence. Did you try debugging it? Print the intermediate steps, examine the stack content? Single-step?

Answer (score 1):

The code attempts to implement a postfix expression evaluator.  To make it work, you should ignore spaces in `evaluate()` and test for errors:

```
void freeStack(Stack *stack) {
    free(stack->array);
    free(stack);
}

int evaluate(const char *expression) {
    int result = -1;
    size_t len = strlen(expression);
    Stack *stack = createStack(len);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len;) {
        cc = expression[i++];
        if (isdigit(cc)) {
            int operand = 0;
            while (i < len && isdigit((unsigned char)expression[i]))
                operand = operand * 10 + expression[i++] - '0';
            push(stack, operand);
        } else
        if (isspace(cc)) {
            continue;
        } else
        if (cc == '+' || cc == '-') {
            if (isEmpty(stack)) {
                printf("syntax error\n");
                freeStack(stack);
                return -1;
            }
            int operand1 = pop(stack);
            if (isEmpty(stack)) {
                printf("syntax error\n");
                freeStack(stack);
                return -1;
            }
            int operand2 = pop(stack);
            switch (cc) {
              case '+':
                push(stack, operand2 + operand1);
                break;
              case '-':
                push(stack, operand2 - operand1);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            printf("invalid character: %c\n", cc);
            freeStack(stack);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    result = pop(stack);
    if (!isEmpty(stack)) {
        printf("missing operators\n", cc);
        freeStack(stack);
        return -1;
    }
    freeStack(stack);
    return result;
}
```

With this postfix notation, the expression should not be `7-5-1+2` but `7 5-1-2+` or `7 5 1 2+--`. Postfix notation can be easily extended to support other operators because you don't need to handle operator precedence.  Parsing C-like arithmetic expressions is more complicated.

Furthermore, using `scanf("%s", expression);` to read the expression is incorrect because `scanf()` will only read a single word, hence a single operand and `%s` will cause a buffer overflow for long inputs.  Use `if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", expression) != 1) break;` or `fgets(expression, sizeof expression, stdin)` after reading and discarding the pending newline.

Comment: Also you cannot use `scanf("%s"` to read a string with spaces, `fgets` recommended instead.

Comment: @n.m.: I agree with your recommandation, but mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is tricky as we all know.

Comment: Right, just ditch `scanf` together with the entire menu thing.

Comment: @n.m.: yes, but still not enough as `fgets()` may read a line fragment if the input is too long...

Comment: If the line is too long, you can detect it. `scanf("%s"` just sends your program to neverland.

Comment: @n.m.: of course `scanf("%s", ...)` is a **NO NO**